# Javascript: HTML5 Video.src = Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, video

I hope this thread finds everyone healthy!

getUserMedia is not supportd in IE so i have used (successfully) flash fallback to stream user webcam though flash.

For face detection i am using headtrackr.js, which expects you are streaming webcam though a video element and in my case i am using flash instead of video element.

My question is how can change source of a video element to get it's stream from flash stream?

I tried the following which didn't work...

```
var flashInput = document.getElementById('XwebcamXobjectX');
var videoInput = document.getElementById('videoInput');
var videoInput.src = flashInput;
```

I hope somebody answers. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to switch the `videoInput.src` based on  the type of browser and keeping with the same example say IE?

Comment: @JordanDavis
yes, I just want a simple solution to copy flash stream to a video element.

Comment: Use the `navigator.userAgent` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator to detect the type of browser, another way of doing it would be to use IE conditional comments http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html so if it is IE it will override your other code just make sure it's below if you choose the later.

Comment: @JordanDavis My question is not about detecting IE.
My question is how to change source of a video element to get it's stream from a flash object?

Comment: ahhh okay got it now, yea it's deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia and even the new ECMA 6 Standard for IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia doesn't have it, here is a good article while I narrow down your answer http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Yea headtracker.js just doesn't support it, I mean it says clearly their based on WebRTC/getUserMedia.... I took a look around and this framework looks way more developed https://trackingjs.com/ they support IE 9+ with partial support for 8

Comment: @JordanDavis I am sorry to say your answers are not relevent to my question. My question is not even about head tracking or browser detection. It is only about copying stream from one elment to another element!!!!!!!!!!!!